# CorePlot: Change Y axis to start at 3, not 0

Tags: core-plot

[image]

I'm using CorePlot 2.3 to generate a single graph "scatter" plot in my iOS 11.3 app.

How to start the Y axis at a value other than 0?

The Y axis currently starts at 0.0 and goes to 10.0. I want to change it so it goes from 3.0 to 10.0. (Data values < 3.0 will generally be = 0.0 and can be ignored or bottom out at the X axis).

How can I do this?

```
CPTXYGraph *newGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CPTTheme *theme      = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
[newGraph applyTheme: theme];
self.graph = newGraph;

CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)self.view;    
hostingView.collapsesLayers = NO; 
hostingView.hostedGraph = newGraph;

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)newGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-12.0) length:@(_total_frames/1.2)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(0.0) length:@(10.0)]; 
plotSpace.globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-15.5) length:@(_total_frames+20)];
plotSpace.globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-1.5) length:@(12.5)];

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)newGraph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *xAxis                    = axisSet.xAxis;
//  .  .  .
CPTXYAxis *yAxis                    = axisSet.yAxis;
yAxis.majorIntervalLength           = @(0.5);
yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval         = 4;
yAxis.orthogonalPosition            = @(0.0);
yAxis.labelingPolicy                = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval; 
yAxis.labelTextStyle                = yAxisLabelTextStyle; 
yAxis.titleLocation                 = @(plotSpace.yRange.midPoint.intValue);
yAxis.title                         = @"D  I  A  M  E  T  E  R ,  m m";
yAxis.titleRotation                 = 1.57; // 90 degrees in radians
yAxis.titleOffset                   = 20.0;
yAxis.titleTextStyle                = axisTitleTextStyle;
yAxis.delegate                      = self;
yAxis.visibleRange                  = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(0.0) length:@(10.0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `visibleRange` or `gridLinesRange` unless you need the extra control over the appearance. Right now, the `visibleRange` is restricting the visible part of the y-axis to 3.0 to 9.0.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the `visibleRange` and `gridLinesRange` statements. But the problem appears that the `plotSpace.yRange` statement has no effect. I can set the values to anything, and the Y axis goes to +/- infinity.

Comment: Is the `plotSpace` variable initialized to the correct plot space when setting the ranges? It's not clear from the code in the question.

Comment: Yes. I do a `CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)newGraph.defaultPlotSpace;`. In the debugger, when I set the yRange, it's this object: `<CPTXYPlotSpace: 0x106b522f0>`. After setting, it has this value: `<<CPTPlotRange: 0x1017c0540> {3, 10}>`. No other yRange assignments in the code. Note: My `newGraph` is created as: `CPTXYGraph *newGraph = [ [ CPTXYGraph alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectZero ];` And `plotSpace` is: `CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)newGraph.defaultPlotSpace;`

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? It might help us determine what's going wrong.

Comment: I have a screenshot. What is the process for uploading to SO? Or does the image have to be available from an external site?

Comment: Do you ever call `-scaleToFitPlots:` or other methods that modify the plot space? I'm at a loss to explain the problem since if nothing else, the `globalYRange` should restrict the possible range even after other attempts to change the `yRange`. I see you're keeping two references to the graph. Make sure the `self.graph` and `hostingView.hostedGraph` are always the same, or eliminate `self.graph` and always refer to the hosted graph when you need it. You could also temporarily implement a plot space delegate and set a breakpoint to find out where the plot space is changing.

Comment: No `-scaleToFitPlots:`, and I removed the extraneous `self.graph` reference. I guess I'll have to use it the way it is. Thanks for all the help!